# Create a function to flip every n characters in a string. Output should have no commas in it, but my output does

Tags: javascript, string, loops, methods

```
var input = 'a short example';
var output = flipEveryNChars(input, 5);
```

The result should be ohs axe trelpma, but my result is o,h,s, ,ax,e, ,t,re,l,p,m,a.  Why are there still commas after using .join?

```js
//function definition
function flipEveryNChars(input, n) {
  // split string into separate characters
  var splitStr = input.split(''); // splits every character and reassigned to new var
  var resultStr = []; // push into new array and return result as a string
  var incrementN = n;
  // iterate through input string

  for (let i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    resultStr.push(splitStr.slice(i, incrementN));; // slices through i to incremtN
    // console.log('each iteration:', resultStr)
    i += n - 1 // increment by original n - 1 since i++  every loop
    incrementN += n // increment by original n
  }

  //iterate through new array
  for (let j = 0; j < resultStr.length; j++) {
    resultStr[j].reverse(); // reverse to flip characters
  }
  return resultStr.join("");
}

var input = 'a short example';
var output = flipEveryNChars(input, 5);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: resultStr is an array of arrays, so a simple join won't work.  Try `return resultStr.flat().join("");`

Comment: Please consider writing up an answer and marking it as accepted if you have found an answer and one is not written yet.